# Fetch GET request all header information are blank

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, fetch

I'm making a javascript fetch request to a PHP backend REST API, where I'm sending a token via the header.

However, when I try to get the header information using PHP CodeIgniter, the header details are all blank arrays.

How can I fix this issue, here is my code

**Javascript**

```
fetch(`URL`, {
    method: 'GET',
    withCredentials: true,
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token
    }
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      DO SOMETHING WITH THE RESPONSE
    })
```

**PHP**

```
$headers = $this->request->getHeaders();
echo json_encode($headers);
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

**Output**

```
Accept: {}
Accept-Encoding: {}
Accept-Language: {}
Authorization: {}
Cdn-Loop: {}
Cf-Connecting-Ip: {}
Cf-Ipcountry: {}
Cf-Ray: {}
Cf-Request-Id: {}
Cf-Visitor: {}
Cookie: {}
Dnt: {}
Host: {}
Referer: {}
Sec-Ch-Ua: {}
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: {}
Sec-Fetch-Dest: {}
Sec-Fetch-Mode: {}
Sec-Fetch-Site: {}
User-Agent: {}
X-Forwarded-For: {}
X-Forwarded-Proto: {}
```

Why is it retrieving empty arrays and how can I fix it, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you nead to add rewrite on to htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

Comment: Hi, yes that is on, I only posted that part of the `.htaccess` because people are saying that is missing in `.htaccess` in other questions. But it's there in the default `.htaccess` in CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `mod_fastcgi` then add the below config  in your
`<VirtualHost></VirtualHost>`

**NOTE :  Please change `php7.0-fpm.sock` and `php7-fcgi` with your php version**

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
  SetHandler php7-fcgi .php
  Action php7-fcgi /php7-fcgi virtual
  Alias /php7-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi
  FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi -socket /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
</IfModule>
```

If it still not work then try the solution listed here: https://dealer4dealer.nl/serverinrichting-woocommerce-restapi/